# how to fetch current location with permission android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm back after a while to android development. I want to have my current latitude and longitude and display it with a toast, unfortunately, it doesn't work . I added location permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

And here is my MainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
        
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            fetchLocation()
        }
    
        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            fetchLocation()
        }
    
        private fun fetchLocation() {
            val task: Task<Location> = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ){
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 101)
                return
            }
            task.addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it != null){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "${it.latitude} - ${it.longitude}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("LOCATION", "${it.latitude} - ${it.longitude}")
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

My question is why the function fetchLocation() isn't triggering after accepting permission and activating the GPS. Help me please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Last location return null sometimes
Use location call back with fused location provider
Edit - https://gist.github.com/kedarmp/26b5697f257d5d0d9f8f2cefe9944ddc
Checkout this gist.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet or some documentation (quoting the helpful bits) which could help the OP? This answer is no more than a comment. :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).